# How to completely stop/reset/reinitialize Matter.js canvas/world/engine/instance

Tags: javascript, matter.js

I have an instance of Matter.js on the screen such as a game, and want to completely start over from scratch when the user/player clicks a "new game" button:

```
const { Engine, Render, Runner, World, Bodies, Mouse, MouseConstraint, Body, Events } = Matter;

    //movement setup
    const engine = Engine.create();
    const { world } = engine;

    let render;
    let runner;

const startGame = document.querySelector('#start');
startGame.addEventListener('click', event => {

    event.preventDefault();

    //hide 'choose difficulty' 
    const chooseDifficulty = document.querySelector('.options');
    chooseDifficulty.classList.add('hidden');

    //get selected difficulty
    const difficulty = document.querySelector('input[name=difficulty]:checked').value;

    //set number of horizontal/vertical cells based on difficulty selected
    switch(difficulty) {
        case 'easy':
            cellsHorizontal = 6;
            cellsVertical = 4;
            break;
        case 'medium':
            cellsHorizontal = 14;
            cellsVertical = 10;
            break;
        case 'hard':
            cellsHorizontal = 25;
            cellsVertical = 15;
            break;
    }

    createMaze();
});

const createMaze = () => {
        //show controls
        // document.querySelector('.controls').classList.remove('hidden');
        console.log(document.querySelector('.controls').scrollHeight)
        //set size of movement.js canvas/world
        const worldWidth = document.querySelector('.canvas').scrollWidth;
        const worldHeight = document.querySelector('.canvas').scrollHeight;

        console.log(document.querySelector('.canvas').scrollHeight)
        console.log(worldHeight);

        //length of one side of one cell
        const unitLengthX = worldWidth/cellsHorizontal;
        const unitLengthY = worldHeight/cellsVertical;

        //disable gravity & render the world
        engine.world.gravity.y = 0;
        world.gravity.x = 0;
        render = Render.create({
            element: document.querySelector('.canvas'),
            engine: engine,
            options: {
                width:worldWidth,
                height:worldHeight,
                wireframes:false
            }
        });

        Render.run(render);
        runner = Runner.create();
        Runner.run(runner, engine);

        //Outer edges
        const edges = [
            /*top*/Bodies.rectangle((worldWidth/2),0,worldWidth,5, {isStatic:true}),
            /*bottom*/Bodies.rectangle((worldWidth/2),worldHeight,worldWidth,5, {isStatic:true}),
            /*left*/Bodies.rectangle(0,(worldHeight/2),5,worldHeight, {isStatic:true}),
            /*right*/Bodies.rectangle(worldWidth,(worldHeight/2),5,worldHeight, {isStatic:true})
        ];

        World.add(world, edges);
}
```

This creates a canvas inside a `.canvas` div on the page that takes up the whole screen, with solid edges on the outside so Bodies can't fall through any direction.

In this instance (not included here), I've create a random maze with a rectangle as the goal and a circle to move around using the WASD or arrow keys, and an event handler for a collision between those two which pops up a previously hidden div with a z-index of 1 to go on top of the map, which contains a "Start Over" button which, when clicked, will take the player back to a difficulty selection and then they can generate a brand new maze.

Here's code for that "Start Over" button where I want to clear the entire Matter instance/canvas/world/engine before giving the option to choose a difficulty and create a new maze:

```
button.addEventListener('click', event => {
            event.preventDefault();
            World.clear(world);
            Engine.clear(engine);
            console.log('reset clicked');
            document.querySelector('.winner').classList.add('hidden');
            document.querySelector('.options').classList.remove('hidden');
        });
```

[Here](https://github.com/liabru/matter-js/issues/143) is where I found the `World.clear` and `Engine.clear` method recommendations, and that worked to remove all the elements from the current canvas.

However what I'm running into is that when the player chooses a new difficulty and clicks the "Go" button, a whole new canvas inside the existing `world` gets created, next to/below the old, now empty, canvas.

How do I get rid of that old canvas in order to completely reinitialize?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess the [Docs](https://brm.io/matter-js/docs) assume that devs can put two and two together from the documentation in order to figure this out, but it took me several hours to find/figure out that I needed to combine [this other post](https://github.com/liabru/matter-js/issues/564) with the one originally referenced to get this for the "Start Over" button event:

```
button.addEventListener('click', event => {
            event.preventDefault();
            World.clear(world);
            Engine.clear(engine);
            Render.stop(render);
            Runner.stop(runner);
            render.canvas.remove();
            render.canvas = null;
            render.context = null;
            render.textures = {};
            console.log('reset clicked');
            document.querySelector('.winner').classList.add('hidden');
            document.querySelector('.options').classList.remove('hidden');
        });
```

Specifically the `Render` and `Runner` class methods/property clear-outs.
You have to stop both of them, then remove the `render` itself and clear the other properties for both `render` and `runner`.

One VERY important thing to note is that I had to declare `engine`, `world`, `render`, and `runner` globally, and then assign them in the `createMaze` function.

Also important, as I found in another post (can't find where it was now) that if you don't stop the `Runner`, the runner/animation will get faster each time the canvas is re-created.

The function is run initially at load, and then again after clearing out the World/canvas with the "Start Over" button, so those variables need to be global.

---

I have to be honest and admit that 1) I'm new, and not super knowledgeable/practiced in initializing/reinitializing, and 2) I'm not the best/most thorough at reading through docs, so this may have been obvious somewhere and I just didn't take the time to find it.

To be more honest, I've been led to believe that no one completely reads docs on everything they use, right? Maybe I've just seen too many "being a developer means pasting from stackoverflow all day" memes.

Comment: don't forget to also disable events. I'm also new. just noticed that events are still running in the background even after all of the above. example:

Events.off(engine, 'beforeUpdate', eventCallback);

Comment: I had a very similar problem. My Scene got very laggy after a few menu toggles & I realized I had an issue with stuff loading over and over again. Your solution helped me speed it up. However,  I have no "Runner" in my code (just using it to aminate CSS positional values). So yes, everytime things fall down faster.
Which could be intended, as people already got used to the "menu drop" after a couple times, but well, I'd love to control it consciously LOL
How do I actually initialize a Runner?

Comment: Ok, I initialize as:

runner = Runner.create();
Runner.run(runner, engine); 

But it still speeds up. Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm using matter.js inside a React class component. My project is here: https://github.com/NeilSentence/galerie-sens

Comment: @NilsSens Since you did initialize the `runner`, did you then `Runner.clear(runner)` when whatever your action is, is done?

Comment: Yes, I tried Runner.stop(runner). Runner.clear(runner) is "not a function" here.